# How to increase timeout in Mule ESB?

Tags: lucene, mule, esb

There is Lucene indexing on startup of application which takes around 10 - 15 minutes. The project is deployed in Mule ESB which is restarting abruptly in between startup.

Is there any way to change timeout of Mule ESB so that it deploys application successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In conf\wrapper.conf following is parameter where you can increase Startup Timeout:

wrapper.startup.timeout=9000

Answer (score 0):

wrapper.startup.timeout in your mule runtime configuration.

go to /{Mule Home}/conf/wrapper.conf